# Github Actions - Publishing Azure Functions with Manged Identities - Server failed to authenticate the request

Tags: azure, azure-functions, github-actions, azure-managed-identity, azure-bicep

I am trying to publish an Azure Function (Linux, Consumption Plan) using  `Azure/functions-action@v1` Github Action with Managed Identity.

Infrastructure has successfuly been created with Bicep, but I'm not able to upload function binaries (C# .NET 7 isolated function).

`AzureWebJobsStorage__accountname` is provided and it seems to be correctly picked up by the action. Adding `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` maunally hasn't solved the issue.

App Registration used for logging in to Azure has `Contributor` role for Subscription.

Error:

```
Using AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName and RBAC for Blob access.
Error: Execution Exception (state: PublishContent) (step: Invocation)
Error:   Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
```

This is my GitHub action:

```yaml
azure-static-website-publish:
    name: Azure Static Web Apps - Publish
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    needs: [create-infrastructure]
    env:
      DOTNET_VERSION: 7.0.x
      FUNCTIONS_FOLDER: ./MySuperAppFunctions/src
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup DotNet ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}
          dotnet-quality: "ga"
      - name: Azure Login
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_BICEP_APP_REGISTRATION_ID }} # this App Registration has `Contributor` role for Subscription
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
      - name: "Resolve Project Dependencies Using Dotnet"
        shell: bash
        run: |
          dotnet build ./MySuperAppFunctions/src/MySuperAppFunctions.csproj --configuration Release --output ./MySuperAppFunctions/src/output
      - name: "Run Azure Functions Action"
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        with:
          app-name: mysuperapp-functionapp
          package: ./MySuperAppFunctions/src/output
```

Function App config:

[image: function app config]

Full log from a failed pipeline run:

```
Run Azure/functions-action@v1
  with:
    app-name: mysuperapp-functionapp
    package: ./MySuperAppFunctions/src/output
    respect-pom-xml: false
    respect-funcignore: false
    scm-do-build-during-deployment: false
    enable-oryx-build: false
  env:
    DOTNET_VERSION: 7.0.x
    FUNCTIONS_FOLDER: ./MySuperAppFunctions/src
    DOTNET_ROOT: /usr/share/dotnet
    AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT: 
    AZUREPS_HOST_ENVIRONMENT: 
Using RBAC for authentication, GitHub Action will perform resource validation.
(node:2030) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Successfully acquired site configs from function app!
Detected function app sku: Consumption
Warning: Neither AzureWebJobsStorage nor AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName exist in app settings (from Azure Resource Manager with RBAC credential). Please ensure one of them is configured as it is critical for function runtime. For more information, please visit the function app settings reference page: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage
Successfully acquired app settings from function app (RBAC)!
Detected function app language: DotnetIsolated
Will archive ./MySuperAppFunctions/src/output into /home/runner/work/_temp/temp_web_package_8268347911500074.zip as function app content
Will use WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to deploy since RBAC is detected and your function app is on Linux Consumption.
Using AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName and RBAC for Blob access.
Error: Execution Exception (state: PublishContent) (step: Invocation)
Error:   Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
RequestId:a8c894ad-f01e-0039-2690-e08ac1000000
Time:2023-09-06T07:03:45.9025260Z
Error:     RestError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
RequestId:a8c894ad-f01e-0039-2690-e08ac1000000
Time:2023-09-06T07:03:45.9025260Z
    at handleErrorResponse (/home/runner/work/_actions/Azure/functions-action/v1/node_modules/@azure/core-http/dist/index.js:3146:19)
    at /home/runner/work/_actions/Azure/functions-action/v1/node_modules/@azure/core-http/dist/index.js:3082:49
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async StorageRetryPolicy.attemptSendRequest (/home/runner/work/_actions/Azure/functions-action/v1/node_modules/@azure/storage-blob/dist/index.js:14396:24)
    at async StorageClientContext.sendOperationRequest (/home/runner/work/_actions/Azure/functions-action/v1/node_modules/@azure/core-http/dist/index.js:4865:31)
    at async ContainerClient.create (/home/runner/work/_actions/Azure/functions-action/v1/node_modules/@azure/storage-blob/dist/index.js:22665:20)
    at async ContainerClient.createIfNotExists (/home/runner/work/_actions/Azure/functions-action/v1/node_modules/@azure/storage-blob/dist/index.js:22690:25)
Error: Deployment Failed!
```

Comment: did you grant the function app managed identity permission over the storage account ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Here are the roles that I assigned for Function App in a Bicep file:

Storage Queue Data Reader, Storage Queue Data Message Processor, Storage Queue Data Contributor, Storage Queue Data Message Sender, Storage Blob Data Owner, Storage Account Contributor

Answer (score 0):

The warning in the shown output seems to indicate the `AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName` variable is missing. In the screenshot you provide the variable is not *exactly* the same as the letter `N` in `accountname` is lowercase. Since Linux is a case-sensitive platform, lower- and uppercase should match *exactly*.

Your screenshot shows :

`AzureWebJobsStorage__accountname`

it should be:

`AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName`

Comment: Changing casing didn't resolve the issue